# Match string inside function

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I want to search for imports in my node modules from visual studio codes regex search, the problem is that i only want to search for imports that are inside functions and not in the whole file. How would i go about doing this?

```
const a = require('a'); // shouldn't match

function func() {
    const b = require('b'); // should match
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you did try and how it didn't met your requirements?

Comment: You can't, actually.

Comment: How about matching if there are spaces preceeding it? `^\s+.*\brequire\(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the growing popularity of such features (search in functions, search outside of comments, search in strings, etc), VSCode still [doesn't have built-in support](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/11688) for such these.

You'll have to use find with regular expressions for this one, but good luck on building the regex for *"a particular pattern inside a function"*. A good hack that doesn't work all of the time is to detect indentation before your pattern: `^\s+.*YOURPATTERN`

Comment: The hack works good enough for my purpose, thank you so much!